# How to reorder multiple lists (not their elements) in an increasing order in Base R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, sorting

I was wondering how to how reorder 3 distinct lists (i.e., *lists don't share any element with each other*) in an increasing manner?

For example, in the output below, I want the entire second list to take the position of the first list, and the third list take the position of the second list and so on.

**P.S.** My goal is to achieve a function/looping structure to reorder any number of lists.

```
x = list(20:46, 3:7, 6:9)
x[-1] <- Map(setdiff, x[-1], x[-length(x)])
x

# output:

[[1]]    ## FIRST LIST
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46

[[2]]    ## SECOND LIST
 [1] 3 4 5 6 7

[[3]]   ## THIRD LIST
 [1] 8 9
```

Comment: second element and third element of the list share elements with each other. why  do you need to resort the list- what is the end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
reorder <- function(x){
 mins <- sapply(x, min) 
 aux=list()
 i=1
 while (length(mins)>0) {
   aux[[i]] <- x[[which.min(mins)]]
   x <- x[-which.min(mins)]
   mins <- mins[-which.min(mins)]
   i=i+1
 }
return(aux)
}
```

the function will re-arrange your list by the lowest number of its vectors.

for example:

```
x <- reorder(x)
```

will get your desired output

Comment: Thank you! but can your function be modified to reorder the following: `reorder( list(0:40, 0:5 ) )` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are these lists always that way? I mean... like a sequence?

For this particular case, you only need a representative number from each list and then you can put it in order like this:

```
x = list(20:46, 3:7, 6:9)
x[-1] <- Map(setdiff, x[-1], x[-length(x)])
x

require(dplyr)
sapply(x, max) %>% order %>% x[.]

[[1]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1] 8 9

[[3]]
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
```

Is that what you are looking for?